# C++ -reading file lines

Tags: c++

Im using the folowing code to read a file with first and last names in it.

firstname lastname

firstname lastname

```
do
{   in >> tmp2;
    cout << tmp2;
} while(tmp2 != '\n');
```

this however doesn't detect the end of the line so I cannot progress as I get a infinite loop. Note tmp2 is a char.

how can I fix this.

Comment: What's the type `tmp2`?

Comment: Use `std::getline` in combination with `std::string`.

Comment: Pray that nobody will at some point want you to deal with names that have some other number than two components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {   

    ifstream fin("file");
    string first, last, comment;
    while (fin >> first >> last) {
        cout << first << ' ' << last << endl;
        getline(fin, comment); // get the rest annoying strings
    }
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot you can do multiple input streams

Comment: Even though the question isn't particularly well-formed, please format your answer in a cohesive compile-able unit (for posterity's sake). I'd do it myself, but I'm on a phone :)

Comment: Good answer, to add further to this, you don't get newline because `operator>>` of input stream tokenize the data by whitespaces (including newline)

Comment: @Someguy Only works if you know that the format will always be ``firstname lastname`` :)

Comment: whit if I add additional information after the names and dont want that information in the stream how can I stop this from reading the whole file

Comment: @Someguy Assuming that the information and the lastname are separated by spaces or tabs. You could do like the updated code example.

Comment: Actually I can use this in that case if I loop it for after specifying the amount names thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: use a stringstream

```
std::stringstream sstrm;
std::string instr;
while (std::getline(std::cin, instr)) {
    sstrm.str(instr);
    std::string fname, lname;
    sstrm >> fname >> lname;
    std::cout << fname << ' ' << lname << '\n';
}
```

This discard anything after the first two tokens in a line.